# Converting HEX to ASCII in Lua Dissector

Tags: lua, hex, ascii, wireshark

I'm trying to take HEX bytes and display them as their ASCII values. If someone could point me reasonably firmly in the right direction I'd be obliged. Tried any number of uint-type commands, and working with buffer(x, 2) as an argument.

Comment: if you mean to convert a *string* containing hexadecimal numbers, you can use `tonumber` like in `print(string.char(tonumber("56", 16)))` (prints `V`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *hex bytes*, but the relevant functions are:

- [`string.byte`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.byte), which converts chars to numerical codes
- [`string.char`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.char), which converts numerical codes to chars

Comment: I mean a pair of HEX bits, don't know why I decided that was a byte, thanks I'll give those functions a try.

Answer (score 1):

For a single character in hexadecimal, you can use `string.byte` as mentioned by lhf. For longer sequences, you can create a loop in Lua, but that is not very efficient since it involves a lot of copying.

Since Wireshark 1.11.3 there is a [`Struct.fromhex`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Struct.html) function that converts a string of hexadecimal characters to the binary equivalent.

Example:

```
-- From hex to bytes (with no separators)
assert(Struct.fromhex("5753") == "WS")
-- From hex to bytes (using a single space as separator)
assert(Struct.fromhex("57 53", " ") == "WS")
```

Similarly, there is a `Struct.tohex` function that converts from bytes to hex.